# long wave radio receiver circuit

Tags: radio, amplitude-modulation

I wish to build a radio which can receive a 60kHz, amplitude modulated signal.

What is the simplest circuit that will achieve this?

Assuming a ferrite rod in an inductor/capacitor configuration, how would I tune this setup?

Comment: Tune, Amplify then Detect. (LC tune, OP amp, Digital detect.)  
Many OPAmps can do 60kc, without an IF stage.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is transmitted on 60kHz carrier?  This is such a low frequency.

Comment: 60KHz may be wwvb [NIST](http://www.nist.gov/pml/div688/grp40/wwvb.cfm)

Comment: I'm listening for the msf time signal broadcast from England. (I'm in Ireland). Similar to the american wwvb signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you doing a time carrier for Europe.  Ironically there was a discussion early about these types of [antennas](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/58028/11861).  [Here](http://www.pvelectronics.co.uk/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=2) is an example of a module for time code reception in case that is what you're looking for.

Comment: This is what I'm attempting to do but I'd prefer to built the whole thing myself.

Answer (score 2):

I've just done this.  As you want the MSF time code I expect you have a computer to read the result.  I used the onboard soundcard and a few meters of wire into the microphone socket, nothing else https://drtonyr.github.io/MSF60decoder/